# MongoDB schema for this specific csv dataset? (for data vis. purposes)

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have a single csv file with data about schools: their locations, their names and a number of indicator values for each:

> County_id, County_name, Municipality_id, Municipality_name, School_id,
>   School_name, Year, Indicator_1, Indicator_2, Indicator_3 [...]

I am building an interactive JavaScript visualization around this data and would like to serve  it using MongoDB.

Some typical queries would be: (pseudo)

- Get a list of all Schools and their respective locations
- Get all Indicator_1 values for all years for schools in a specific location
- Count the number of schools in a specific location

**1. Based on the data given, how should I set up my MongoDB documents/collections to be able to answer queries such as the above?**
(Hints on what intermediate steps I should take to import and build the schema are also welcome.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For aggregate queries, check out MongoDB's [MapReduce](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/MapReduce). This by default will create new collections based on your map/reduce functions (but can also run in-memory).

You can use [mongoimport](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Import+Export+Tools) to import CSV data into the database, then leverage map/reduce to get the data you want.

Comment: Does this mean I could simply use the repetitious csv as a base for the DB and it will create collections on the fly?

Comment: Edited answer, use `mongoimport`.

Comment: Thanks for the link Rob. Is there no need to split the csv into for example "geographies", "school entities" and "indicators" beforehand or is this a relational way of thinking?

Comment: No need, that's what the map/reduce functions are for. Just throw all the row data into one big collection, use map/reduce to distill them down and aggregate them.

Comment: And yes, getting your head around the non-relational way of thinking is pretty challenging at times :)

Comment: Thanks Rob. This - "Just throw all the row data into one big collection" - was my main concern really. I suppose I should just import the whole thing and start querying and aggregating. Thanks.

Comment: Keep in mind that the big collection is just used as the source for map/reduce, the map/reduce will in turn create a new collection, with the refined data.

Comment: And the map/reduce takes place when? For example, say I wanted to find the "mean value for all schools of a particular geography a particular year". What is the order of events given my original flat csv file?